# How to select multiple rows by using grid.getSelectionModel().select(Indexes) in extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

I want to select multiple rows by using grid.getSelectionModel().select(Indexes) in extjs 4.1
   Anyone knows how to do it?? 
   Here is my code:

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('GridStudents');
var fieldvalues = '2054,2055,2057';
var arr = fieldvalues.split(',');

for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) 
{
  index = grid.store.find('StudentID', arr[j]);
  grid.getSelectionModel().select(j);
}
```

Comment: What's your exact problem? What's your current result?

Comment: This code Just select only one row but I need to select multiple rows on grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your selection model must have mode `MULTI` or `SIMPLE`.

Then you can use method `selectRange(startRow, endRow)` when you want to select bunch of records which are in one block.

You can also use select and pass array of records or select one by one using index.

Both this function accepts another parameter `keepExisting`. When set to true, existing selection is kept (as name suggests).

Also you pass `j` to `select` method instead of `index`.

So easiest fix would be:

```
for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) 
{
    var index = grid.store.find('StudentID', arr[j]);
    grid.getSelectionModel().select(index, true);
}
```

If your model is configured for multiple selection, it should work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ofLb3Ls/3/

As an alternative you can try this code:

```
var grid = sender.up('grid');
var fieldvalues = '2054,2055,2057';
var arr = fieldvalues.split(',');
var records = Ext.Array.filter(
    grid.store.data.items,
    function(r) {
        return arr.indexOf(''+r.get('StudentID')) !== -1;
     }
 );
 grid.getSelectionModel().select(records);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ofLb3Ls/4/

Comment: If you have everything configured properly it should work. See my fiddle, maybe you'll find error: http://jsfiddle.net/7ofLb3Ls/3/

Comment: I've just found out that you pass `j` to select method instead of `index`. After changing `j` to `index` you should be good. BTW you should declare index in loop, otherwise you will use global.

Comment: I have checked your fiddle. Ya its working perfectly fine in your fiddle. But in my case my button is on a web page and this buttons handler it opens new Extjs window. And grid is on  this window and i want to show previously selected rows/records on grid present in Ext.widget('window').

Comment: Button or grid location doesn't matter. You must have some error. Try reproduce it on your own fiddle otherwise it'll be guessing.

Comment: This is working but I need to click 3 times (length of array) on button.

Comment: I've modified my answer, try second snippet.